# PyCharm doing a refactor on an ID not replacing it in associated CSS and JS files

Tags: javascript, html, css, pycharm, refactoring

I tried to perform a refactor on an element's ID by highlighting it and right clicking to perform a refactor to rename it.

However, all that PyCharm did was rename the element's ID without searching for it in the other files associated in the project.

Is there an option / plugin that I can use to be able to rename all times an ID is used in my JavaScript and CSS when I rename it in the HTML file with a refactor?

Comment: The refactor will work if your HTML has a reference to the CSS file, otherwise the refactor won't be able co-relate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order for PyCharm to refactor your ID correctly, there needs to be an association between the file you're updating the ID in and the CSS that's related to that ID.

Even though you might have defined that ID in a CSS file, it might be possible that the ID is defined in *multiple* CSS files. If you were to refactor an ID and it changed it for *all* CSS files, it wouldn't really be doing the what is intended by "refactor".

If you want to have it change everywhere, you might just want to do a global find & replace, instead of using the "refactor" option.